# Interactive grid update all rows with page item value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would be grateful if any of you could advise me on this need. I checked Google but came up empty-handed, so I'm writing the criteria here. This is a universal necessity, in my opinion, but as a rookie, I don't completely get the tool's possibilities.

Requirement: Business users want to search for rows depending on criteria and change one specific column in all of those rows based on data in a lov. I attempted to demonstrate the technique below.

Please advise if this is possible in Apex, and if any one of you have written any blog post about it please direct me to the link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok9Wf.png)

Comment: Please try to use a title for your question that summarises the problem you're trying to solve "Go back APEX Subscribed New Post Inputs needed on a Interactive Grid requirement" doesn't give much information so I updated it. This is particularly useful for other users searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to update all records. In my case there is an editable interactive grid with a static id "ig-tickets" and a column status. The page has a button with a dynamic action of type "execute javascript" that updates all records to status "CLOSED".

I tested it with the scenario you described. Do a search, then execute the javascript to update all records - it worked fine. In my example the value "CLOSED" is hardcoded but you could take a page item value as well using the `apex.item( "P_ITEM" ).getValue()` syntax.

```
apex
  .region("ig-tickets")
  .widget()
  .interactiveGrid("getViews")
  .grid.view$.grid("selectAll");
var grid = apex.region("ig-tickets").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
var model = grid.model;
var record = grid.getSelectedRecords();
var newvalue = "CLOSED";

record.forEach(function (object, index) {
  rec = record[index];
  model.setValue(rec, "STATUS", newvalue);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, it seems helpfull. Where to add the update statement if you can advise. Also, can we pass all those IG rows to a PLSQL procedure as parameters?

Comment: If you have an IG on a table, then the apex builder will generate a native IG process for you that takes care of the updates. May I suggest you do some research on IG first and ask a new question if you don't find the solution. Followup questions in comments are very hard to answer.